# c++ && conditional never executed

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a program for an assignment that computes the rate for a long distance call, that takes in the starting time and length of call and outputs the gross cost and net cost. 
There are several parameters involved, which i've implemented in conditional statements,

- Any call started at or after 6:00 pm (1800) but before 8:00 am (800) is discounted 50%.
- All calls are subject to a 4% federal tax.
- The regular rate is $0.35 per minute.
- Any call longer than 60 minutes receives a 16% discount on its cost (after any other discount is subtracted but before tax is added).

However, the first conditionals code is never executed and I've tried several different operands and still have not figured it out.

```
#import <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

//declare variables
int startTime;
int callLength;
double grossCost = 0;
double netCost;
const double callRate = 0.35;
const double fedTax = 0.04;
const double discount1 = 0.50;
const double discount2 = 0.16;


//begin user prompt
cout << "Enter start time: " << endl;
cin >> startTime;
cout << "Enter length of call in minutes: " << endl;
cin >> callLength;

//define our grossCost
grossCost = (callLength * callRate);

//lez do some conditionals
    if ((startTime >= 1800) && (startTime <= 800)){

        netCost = grossCost - (grossCost * discount1);
        netCost *= fedTax;
    }

    else if (callLength > 60){
        netCost = grossCost - (grossCost * discount2);
        netCost *= fedTax;
    }
    else{
        netCost = (grossCost * fedTax);
    }

    //print out our final costs
    cout << "gross cost : " << "$" << grossCost << endl;
    cout << "net cost: " << "$" << netCost << endl;

    return 0;

    }
```

So, when trying an input of:

```
Enter start time: 2322
Enter length of call in minutes: 67
gross cost : $23.45
net cost: $0.78792
```

The netcost is not being evaluated correctly, as it is skipping the first conditional, even though the values of startTime meet the parameters. 
The output should be:

```
    Enter start time: 2322
    Enter length of call in minutes: 67    
    gross cost: $23.45
    net cost: $10.24
```

I'm not looking for someone to do my homework, just some pointers to lead me in the right direction, i've gone over the conditional several times and I'm still confused as to why it's not evaluating. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Numbers that are both larger than 1800 and smaller than 800 are quite rare...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a logic error here: a number can not be greater or equal than 1800 *and* less or equal than 800 at the same time. Revise the first conditional. I would break it in two parts

`if((time >= 1800 & <=2400) || (time >= 0 && time <= 800))`.

The actual logical mistake here is that calls *after 6PM* and *before 8AM* would exist in different days! So we do need two conditions that check on the days' boundaries as well, combined.

*Edit per comment by @Reto Koradi:*

The outcome won't change if we omit the boundary checks. As mentioned above, the gist of the change is to highlight the mutual exclusiveness of th two conditions, which is achieved by swapping the `&&` out with an `||`:

```
if (time >= 1800 || time <= 800)
```

Comment: Excuse me? Rather 18PM is 6PM, and 18 doesn't strictly speaking need a PM suffix, due to it being absolute, i.e. 24-hour based.

Comment: The proposed expression looks more complicated than necessary, unless the input times can be outside the valid range. As long as all values are between 0 and 2400, you don't need the extra conditions to test for those values.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the hint! I sort of program that way, trying to check against as many errors as possible. So, we can simply change the `&&` to a `||`.

Comment: Yes, exactly - when you add "PM" to 1800, which is already in the afternoon, it's like saying you want to add another twelve hours to it! In fact there's no such thing as 18PM. 6PM is 1800. I was joking that 18PM would have to be 0600.

Comment: Fixed 18PM to be 6PM

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
if ((startTime >= 1800) && (startTime <= 800)){
```

The two conditions are mutually exclusive. There is no number greater than 1800 and at the same time smaller than 800. You might want to fix the comparison condition like this (improved for future readers thanks to iksemyonov's comments. Please refer to his answer to this same question)

```
if ((startTime >= 1800) || (startTime <= 800)){
```

Comment: oops, knew I was missing something basic. Thanks Jorge! I need more coffee!

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure this is right either.  He says the start time is AFTER 1800 or BEFORE 800.  I think you need to change && to ||

Comment: Jorge, you miss the actual task OP's been given. You seasure the interval between 18 PM and 8 AM the other way round, so to say. See my answer below.

Comment: @iksemyonov good catch! Right. The logic error was not only the exclusive range, but that it has a rollover.

Comment: Nice wording, I was unfamiliar with such a meaning of the word "rollover"!

Answer (score 2):

The explanation why it's not working is fairly obvious, and already covered in other answers. This expression can never be true because no number is both greater than 1800 and also less than 800.

```
if ((startTime >= 1800) && (startTime <= 800)){
```

The `&&` operator tests for both conditions to be true.

The more interesting part is **why** people make this mistake. And you're neither the first nor the last person to fall into this trap when starting out with logical expressions.

I believe the reason is that in natural language, we use the word "and" in ways that are very different from the logical operator. When you say "before 8 am and after 6 pm", the "and" corresponds much more to the "union" set operation. You're basically defining a set that contains "all times before 8 am" and "all times after 6 pm", which is a set union.

The logical operator that matches the "union" set operation is the logical "or". Any element that is in at least one of the input sets is part of the union. So for the union of two sets, the union is the set with elements that are in the first set **or** the second set.

With that understood, the correct condition is:

```
if ((startTime >= 1800) || (startTime <= 800)){
```

where `||` is the logical "or" operator.

Logical operations working differently from the way they are used in everyday language is not unusual at all. So you always need to be careful when translating language to logical expressions. Another popular example is that "or" in natural language mostly corresponds to an exclusive or, while the "or" operator is inclusive. So if somebody tells you that "you can take it or leave it", it means that you have to decide, while the standard logical "or" operator would actually allow you to do both.

Comment: This is a great response, thank you for breaking down my mistake and providing a good explanation on the logic flow!

Comment: Gah, this is a better answer actually.. Looks like I've stolen one from you Reto Koradi :(

Comment: I've been thinking a lot on the difference between logical operators in the human language and computer / mathematical language, and come to the conclusion that the human kind of operator is downright ambiguous and doesn't match the CS kind 1:1. Which is an interesting fact, per se, and may potentially lead to misunderstanding in everyday life.

Answer (score 1):

How can x > 1800 and x < 800 ever be true at the same time?. If the first is true, the statement will always be false.